# Add controls dynamically on button click in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating an asp.net MVC application in which I want to provide a functionality to add a controls dynamically. I have a form in which there are 2 text boxes for First Name and Last name which serve as a single control. Now an user can add any number of this group of controls. I am able to add these controls on the page using java script. But I do not know how to access the values of these control when the user submits.

Please help in this or suggest another approach

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of the article [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) by Steve Sanderson. It shows you how to do what you are looking for in a clean, MVC style.

Comment: are there any newer, more efficient solutions, given it's been 4 years??

Answer (score 2):

Look at using a Jquery AJAX call for the submit operation.

You can interate through your controls (easy with jquery class selector and $.each) and push the variables into a js variable.
Parse it as JSON and pass the data back to the controller using the ajax call..

Answer (score 1):

If you're coming from a webforms perspective, you're accustomed to adding those new controls programmatically in the codebehind.  Using ASP.NET MVC, you're better off doing this with javascript.

It should be trivial to write a javascript function that adds FirstName1, FirstName2, FirstName3, etc.  In the Controller, inspect the `Request.Form.AllKeys` to determine how many fields were added by the user.

You could also iterate a number in a hidden field called "txtNumFields", then use that as your controlling value in a for loop:

```
int numFields = int.Parse(Request.Form["txtNumFields"]);
for (i==0;i<numFields ;i++)
{
   string firstName = Request.Form["FirstName" + i.ToString()];
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, I tried this approach but Request.Form.AllKeys is always 0. It is not showing any control which I added using javascript. Any help?

Comment: This is the problem, as Request.Form.AllKeys.Count is always 0. So I am not able to access any item in my controller.

Comment: Are you setting an id on each form field?  You also need to make sure the button is of type=submit, and the Action needs to be able to accept a POST (decorate the Action method with [HttpPost]

Comment: Actually I have a div with two text boxes which is inside a main div. Using jQuery I am cloning this child div and adding to the main div, each time the user is clicking "Add one more" button. 

Yes, button is of submit type.